# find sum of maximum possible triangular chord

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am having a binary tree

```
         2
       /   \
      3     4
     / \     \
    5   1     8
   / \       / \
  1   6     9   2
                 \
                  4
```

i want to find the `maximum possible triangular chord info sum` of nodes ( between any two leaves and a node having both left and right child ) in the given tree.

a triangular chord will be

for triangular chord :

just imagine a line between any two leaves, go upward towards root, find a common parent (that can be parent, grandparent, grandgrandparent or even the root itself). While moving upwards, for each leaf ( for any leaf either we have to go upward only left left left .... and so OR either only right right right right .. and so) means ( left leaf will only move `right` upward only and right leaf will move `left` upward only..... So for any single leaf, `we can not move in both direction while moving upwards`).. Now we get a triangular shape.. in which `a side may contain any no. of nodes/links possible`.. NOW, if that `triangular shape does not contain any extra internal branches`. that triangular shape will be a triangular chord.

Do remember that `every leaf node is also always a triangular chord` (It is just to create the default cases if the binary tree do not have any triangular shaped chord)

now

```
    maximum triangular chord will be that triangular chord 
which have maximum total in sum of all its node info.
```

we are required to `return that maximum total.`

```
    If we do not have triangular shaped chord.. 
then we have to return the leaf with maximum info.
```

for example

```
   8                    
  / \
 2   3
      \
       3
```

is a triangular chord

```
  8                     
  / \                   
 2   3
  \   \
   4   1
```

only subtree with single node 4 will be maximum triangular chord (as its sum is greater than another triangular chord with single node 1) Not the whole tree will be triangular chord

```
    8                    
   / \
  2   3
 /     \
4       3
```

is a triangular chord

so the solution of the very first tree on the first line of question is

```
8+9+2+4 = 23
```

i am badly trapped in this problem.

I have a rough approach

I will recursively call leftchild as root of subtree and find the left maximum triangular chord sum
then same for rightchild as root of subtree.

add the max of leftmax and rightmax, and the add to rood node and return

in c++ mycode is :

```
int maxtri(node* n) 
{
  if(n) 
  {
    lsum = maxtri(n->left);
    rsum = maxtri(n->right);
    k = maxof(lsum,rsum);
    return (n->info + k);
  }
}
```

edit : my another recursive approach

```
int l =0, r =0;
int maxtri(node* n)
{
 if (n == NULL) return 0;
 if (!(n->left) && !(n->right)) return n->info;
 if ((n->left) && (n->right))
 {
  l = maxtri(n->left);
  r = maxtri(n->right);
 }
 if ((n->left) && !(n->right)) 
 {  
  l = l + maxtri(n->left);
 }
 if (!(n->left) && (n->right)) 
 {
  r = r + maxtri(n->right);
 }
 return (l+r+n->info);
}
```

i have doubt on my approach.

can anyone give another solution.??

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried? Show us some code.

Comment: i want to get the right approach before start coding. so i gave the  my rough approach. and rough coding as well. now plz correct my approach.

Comment: that's not really what StackOverflow is for, read the [faq]. Also, which programming language is that?

Comment: i was having a problem.. i gave my rough approach and i am not finding its correct.. so i asked the question here to get better answer.. i have not wrote a 'single line' question, not anything offensive,.. rather i gave proper explanation, gave my full effort to make it clear.. whats wrong in it.. and why i am downvoted for this..?

Comment: and by the way.. the programming langauge is c++.. i have used pointers general approach of tree.

Comment: i apologize i had not gave the coding part. earlier. but now i gave the approach and also the coding part as well..

Comment: i am a newbie and i am looking for some help from my seniors on stackoverflow.. do any no. of downvotes... i do not care...... but i would be thankful if anyone of you post any answer..

Comment: Does a triangular chord means "a subtree with a root and two lines of children and grandchildren and so on that are two straight lines, or a single root"? Some more definition may help us in trying to approach this.

Comment: kindly go through my edit part **edit : for triangular chord :**

Comment: also go through **edit : my another recursive approach**

Comment: So excluding the leaf nodes, this tree http://pastebin.com/PNCPienR only has 2 triangular chords. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @nhahtdh yes.. absolutely correct.. there are two triangular chord one with sumtotal = 5+6+1 = 12 and another with 8+9+2+4 = 23 .. and the system should return maximum means 23

Comment: @nhahtdh i was talking about the binary tree in my question (given in first line of my question) and your link, in the comment, does not have any nodes.. as i can see.

Comment: @Koka: It is a complete tree with 2 (3?) levels - 7 nodes. The value at the nodes is irrelevant - I just want to ask how many triangular chords there are in such tree.

Comment: @nhahtdh then it (complete tree with 2 (3?) levels - 7 nodes.) also has 2 triangular chords..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this logic:
For each node traverse the left portion and right portion, if you find any branches then don't consider this node in your calculation else consider this. Moreover, for the part of calculation node should have left & right nodes or it should be leaf node.

Note: I have not tested it properly but i believe it should work.

```
// Node by Node traverse the tree  

void addSum(Node *head, vector<int>& sum)
{
if (head == NULL)
    return;
else {
    int s = traverseThisNode(head);
    sum.push_back(s); // Add to vector
    addSum(head->left, sum);
    addSum(head->right, sum);
}
}

// For each node traverse left & right  

int traverseThisNode(Node *head)
{
if (head && head->left && head->right) {
    Node *temp = head;  // To traverse right portion of this node
    int sum = head->value;
    while(head->left) {   // Traverse right
        head = head->left;
        sum = sum + head->value;
        if (head->right) {  // Condition to check if there is any branching
            sum = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    while(temp->right && sum != 0) {  // Traverse Right now
        temp = temp->right;
        sum = sum + temp->value;
        if (temp->left) { // Condition to check if there is any branching
            sum = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    return sum;
} else if (head && !head->left && !head->right) {
    return head->value;   // To add leaf node
}
return 0;
}

Now you have vector containing all the value of triangular in the tree, traverse it and   
find the maximum.
int maximum() 
{
  // Traverse the vector "sum" & find the maximum
}
```

Comment: Time complexity of your solution = O(NlogN + maxvector())

Comment: instead of using vector and externally calculating maximum element, we can use a variable max and store the max result up to the traversal.. at last we will have max as the final returning result.

Comment: @koka: Yes we can do some optimization on finding maximum..I focused more on finding first the triangular in the tree so I dint think about this part much :)

Answer (score 0):

I write the pseudocode for my approach, as far as I have understood the question.

```
Max = min_value; //possibly 0 if no negative value is allowed for nodes.
sum = 0;
for each node in the tree
    temp = node;
    sum+= temp->data  //collects data at the current level, the current level may be leaf too.
    Until temp->left is not null, // Traversing uni-directionally to the left most deep and collecting data.
       temp = temp->left
       sum+=temp->data 
    Until temp->right is not null,  // Traversing uni-directionally to the right most deep and collecting data.
       temp = temp->right
       sum+= temp->data 

    if(sum > Max)
      Max = sum;

    sum = 0;  



print Max;
```

Comment: consider a complete binary tree.. now the pair of leftmost leaf and rightmost leaf will always consider the root of tree as common parent... which is unusual to form a triangular chord, as there are always internal branches (for height of 3 or more), at least in case of complete binary tree.. I think you missed to consider about internal branches..